# Stability and Asymptotic Stability of Rational Matrix Solutions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If $X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix solution of $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ on $a<t<\infty$ and suppose the entries of $X(t)$ are rational functions of the variable t in the form $x_{ij}=p_{ij}(t)/q_{ij}(t)$.

Prove that $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ is Lyapunov stable iff degree of $p_{ij} \le$ degree $q_{ij}$.
Furthermore, prove that $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ is asymptotically Lyapunov stable iff degree of $p_{ij} <$ degree $q_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.

As background, a solution $\phi(t)$ is Lyapunov stable if given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that when $|\xi-\phi(\beta)|<\delta$ $|x(t,\beta,\xi)-\phi(t)|<\epsilon$ for $\beta \le t \le T$.  The solution is said to be Lyapunov asymptotically stable if it is Lyapunov stable and there exists $\kappa >0$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}|x(t,\beta,\xi)-\phi(t)|=0 $ whenever $|\xi-\phi(\beta)|<\kappa$.

Intuitively I can understand that if $x_{ij}=p_{ij}(t)/q_{ij}(t)$ is a constant function ie degree of $p_{ij} =$ degree $q_{ij}$, then the function is lyapunov stable, and if degree of $p_{ij} <$ degree $q_{ij}$, then the function will decay as t increases so it will be asymptotically stable.  However, I am struggling to start a more rigorous proof of these statements.